# Sqlalchemy union of two similar tables

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have two sql tables (messages, messages_processed), both are similar. messages_processed table has one column extra than messages one, other columns data types/structure are same in both. While showing all messages (processed/regular) for a particular user, a union of these two tables should be applied.

```
Class Message(object):
  def __init__(self, sender_id, text, user_id):
     self.sender_id = sender_id
     self.text = text
     self.user_id = user_id
     self.categories = [] #(N:M relation)
Class MessageProcessed(object):
  def __init__(self, sender_id, text, user_id, action):
     self.sender_id = sender_id
     self.text = text
     self.user_id = user_id
     self.categories = [] #(N:M relation)
     self.action = action
```

I cannot change the existing structure of table. I need to do some thing like this which will result array of orm objects with N:M mapping.

```
session.query(Message).filter(Message.user_id==12)
                      .union(session.query(MessageProcessed)
                                    .filter(MessageProcessed.user_id==12)).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you cannot use UNION in your case because each SELECT statement within the UNION must have the same number of columns.

Comment: Thanks. action is not required in the final result. Union should be with all other fields except for action. Simply put, can the result be objects of Message.

Comment: Do you have any problems with query? It looks absolutely correct.

Comment: I get this error: _All selectables passed to CompoundSelect must have identical numbers of columns; select #1 has 13 columns, select #2 has 14_

Comment: So is there an option to achieve that?